# Why is my delegate becoming nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates, protocols

I've done this delegation pattern a million times. On the million and one-th time I'm getting a nil delegate:

```
CatViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Cat" bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];
vc.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{
        DDLogWarn(@"[%@ %@] delegate: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD, vc.delegate); //here the delegate is valid
    }];
```

---

```
@protocol CatViewControllerDelegate;

@interface CatViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <CatViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol CatViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)catViewController:(CatViewController*)catVC didFinishWithSuccess:(BOOL)success;

@end
```

However, in viewDidLoad of CatViewController, self.delegate is already nil, and of course is nil when I try to do this:

```
    [self.delegate catViewController:self didFinishWithSuccess:YES];
```

Why is the catViewController's delegate becoming nil?

Comment: Did you modify the delegate anywhere else ? If not, I think the delegate instance must be deallocated.

Comment: I believe that viewDidLoad gets called after your instantiate the initial view controller but before you set the delegate.  you can test this theory by placing string in viewdidLoad: and then placing a string in setDelegate: and check which gets called first.  I suggest that since you are trying to use the delegate so early on you may want to create an initWithDelegate: method.

Comment: Also, when you get the view from the storyboard, it automatically loads the views...which means the views would be loaded be the time you get a reference to the Viewcontroller, thus viewDidLoad: would be called already.

Comment: I'm actually not using the delegate until I press a button. But it's already nil in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the CatViewController was embedded in a Navigation Controller in the Storyboard. Therefore instantiateInitialViewController was not returning a CatViewController, although everything appeared fine on screen. The fix:

```
UINavigationController *navVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Cat" bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];
CatViewController *catVC = navVC.viewControllers[0];
catVC.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
vc.delegate = self;
```

Whatever `self` is, it is being deleted by the time your new view controller's viewDidLoad gets called. To test this theory, put a dealloc method in that class and put a breakpoint in it.

Comment: I did this. I can confirm that dealloc does not get called in the class that creates the CatViewController.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try to declare the delegate like this instead?

```
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) id <CatViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

Comment: Why would that possibly be better!?